# no more memory for NDSolve

Tags: pde

I am Solving a nonlinear partial differential equation and I have to apply very small steps since I am dealing with a physical phenomenon.But as I decrease the step size and even I am using MaxSteps, I still get the error `no more memory for NDSolve`.

Here is my program:

```
a = 0.05; b = 0.5; L = 20; T = 6 \[Pi]; h = 4;
NDSolve[{b*D[u[t, x], t, t] + a*D[u[t, x], t] == 
   D[u[t, x], x, x] - Sin[u[t, x]], u[0, x] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == h*Sin[t], 
  Derivative[0, 1][u][t, L] == 0}, u, {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, L}, 
 MaxStepSize -> 0.0001, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
```